# How to use E-Commerce layout in Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, e-commerce

[Sample image for desired layout in Xamarin.Forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHNgU.png) 
Hi everyone! I am going to develop an E Commerce mobile app using Xamarin.Forms. I am not sure that what View/Control to use to list/show all the products in product catalogue. I've attached a picture that shows the sample or similar look what I want. IS there such a control in xamarin.forms? If so, what is it and how to use it ? 
Thanks

Comment: Use Grid Layout

Answer (score 0):

There is no such control. You will have to create your own with the existing ones.

Comment: Isn't there any similar control to it ? what existing controls should I use to create my custom control ?